# MVC Data through ActionLink and/or Form

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4

here is the problem im conflicting with:
I have a form, where a user inserts data, along with the data there is information about geo location (address, city etc.).
with this geo information, when user clicks next (using actionlink) im opening a dialog (which is a paritalview) and displaying a google map with location inserted for approval from the user.
afterwards, when user clicks on "approve" button, i want to continue forward to a different action.

at the point im using actionlink, i lose all the data of the form.
if i change the actionlink to a button-submit, the partial view isn't opening at all.

Q: What would be the proper why to do such thing (such a flow of data & UI)??

here is some code attached:
View.cshtml

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm())
     {         
        @Html.EditorFor(x => x.UserInfo)
     @Html.ActionLink("next", "GoogleApprove", "Create", null, new { id = "next", name =   
     "button", value = "next" })
         @*<input type="submit" name="button" id="next" value="next"    
      /<*@
      <div id="dialog"></div>
      }

        $(function () {
        $('#next').click(function () {
           var href = this.href;
           $('#dialog').dialog({
               modal: true,
               height: 720,
               width: 700,
               title 'Verify Location',
               open: function (event, ui) {
                   $(this).load(href, function (result) {
                       $('#googleFrom').submit(function () {
                           $.ajax({
                               url: this.action,
                               type: this.method,
                               data: $(this).serialize(),          
                               success: function (json) {
                                   $('#dialog').dialog('close');
                               }
                           });
                           return false;
                       });
                   });
               }
           });
           return false;
       });
       });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a submit button:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("GoogleApprove", "Create", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "myForm" }))
{         
    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.UserInfo)
    <input type="submit" name="button" id="next" value="next" />
    <div id="dialog"></div>
}
```

and then in a separate javascript file subscribe to the .submit event of this form and open the dialog:

```
$(document).on('submit', '#googleFrom', function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: this.action,
        type: this.method,
        data: $(this).serialize(),          
        success: function (json) {
            $('#dialog').dialog('close');
        }
    });
    return false;
});

$(function() {
    $('#dialog').dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        modal: true,
        height: 720,
        width: 700,
        title 'Verify Location',
        open: function (event, ui) {
            var form = $('#myForm');
            $.ajax({
                url: form.attr('actoin'),
                type: form.attr('method'), 
                data: form.serialize(),
                context: this,
                success: function(result) {
                    $(this).html(result);
                }
            });
        }
    });

    $('#myForm').submit(function() {
        $('#dialog').dialog('open');
        return false;
    });
});
```